# sass watch entire project and add postfix

Tags: sass

I have a project with multiple directories with .sass files in each directory.

I want sass to watch all files and recomplie them if changes happen so `sass --watch projectDir`works great but I also want to add a postfix to all compiled file for example `myfile.sass` will be `myfile.post.css`.

How do I do that?

If I cannot then is there a way to run batch sass commands from file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a build tool such as gulp/grunt/webpack to watch your files and the compile your sass.

here is something that could get you started https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/